# State spaces of AF algebras using Bratteli diagrams

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

AF algebras can be constructed from matrix algebras by using Bratteli diagrams. By Choi's theorem the pure state space of a matrix algebra is a complex projective space. I am assuming that someone has put these together and given the state space of an AF algebra as a limit (using the Bratteli diagram) of finite dimensional manifolds. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction  to read about this.

This is a specialisation to AF algebras of a question I asked earlier which received 8 upvotes but no comments. I have tried to make it more specific.

Comment: Just to clarify, the state space will be an *inverse limit* of the finite dimensional ones (the AF algebra is the closure of the algebraic *direct limit* of finite dimensional semisimple AF algebras).